# Does A5 have a subgroup of order 6?

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to figure out if $A_5$ has a subgroup of order $6$. Rather than a yes/no answer I would prefer if someone could show me how they find their way to the answer. Below is my false attempt at a solution. Ideally I could get some tips on how to fix my attempt, but if it seems a dead end alternate solutions are really appreciated:).

I began by counting the number of elements of each cycle type in S5 so that I could deduce the conjugacy classes and class equation for S5. Next I checked centralizers to determine which were conjugacy classes in A5 and I got the class equation for $A_5$ as $60 = 1 + 12 + 12 + 15 + 20$.

Using the orbit-stabilizer theorem, we can deduce from the order of the last conjugacy class that there is a subgroup of order $3$, namely the centralizer of any element in this conjugacy class, for example $C((12345))={e, (12345), (15432)}$. It is easy to then find a subgroup of order $2$ such as $<(12)(34)>= {e, (12)(34)}$. Since the intersection of these two groups is ${e}$, my hope was that $<(12)(34)>(12345)$ would be a subgroup of order $6$, unfortunately not all the elements commute (If the elements of two subgroups $H$,$K$ commute and their intersection is ${e}$ then $HK$ is a subgroup with order equal to the product of the orders) so I'm left at a dead end.

Comment: $(1,2,3,4,5)$ is an element of order $5$, so it couldn't possibly be contained in a subgroup of order $6$. And your final sentence does not make much sense. Why would you expect all elements to commute? The subgroup you are looking for might be a nonabelian subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: Ah yes, that make sense. So this is definitely a dead end. If the elements of two subgroups H,K commute and their intersection is {e} then HK is a subgroup with order equal to the product of the orders.

Comment: If you want to cheat, you can look at [Twisted S3 in A5](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Twisted_S3_in_A5) and the pages it links at the top of the page.

Comment: *If* you are able to calculate the normalizer of $\langle(123)\rangle$, then you have just to check if it contains an element of order $2$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $\pi\in S_5$ is a permutaion of $\{1,2,3\}$, then either $\pi$ or $\pi\circ (4\,5)$ is an even permutation, i.e., $\in A_5$. This allows us to embed $S_3\to A_5$.

---

Or have fun with geometry: $A_5$ is the symmetry group of the dodekahedron.
It is possible to select $4$ of its $20$ vertices that make up a regular tetrahedron $T_1$. A rotation of the dodekahedron by $72^\circ$ turns $T_1$ into another such tetrahedron $T_2$. Then the subgroup of $A_5$ that fixes $T_1\cup T_2$ turns out to be of isomorphic to $S_3$ (why?)

Answer (score 2):

Although you said that you didn't want a yes/no answer, my hint to you is that the answer is yes, so you should just try to construct a subgroup, $H$, of order 6. Look for elements $\sigma$ and $\rho$ of order 2 or 3. A priori there are two possibilities for $H$ - namely $\mathbb Z_6=\langle\rho, \sigma | \sigma \rho \sigma ^{-1}=\rho, \quad \rho^3=e=\sigma^2\rangle$ and $D_6=\langle\rho, \sigma | \sigma \rho \sigma ^{-1}=\rho^{-1}, \quad \rho^3=e=\sigma^2\rangle. $ $\mathbb Z_6$ has an element of order 6, but no such element exists in $A_5$ - you'd need a product of 2-cycles and a 3-cycles, but since you're only allowed to permute 5 objects, you can only get elements like $(12)(345)$ which are odd, so not in $A_5$. So the only possibility is $D_6$, but if you choose your elements $\sigma$ and $\rho$ well you'll get this.

Comment: You're only "home" if the two elements commute.

Comment: I don't think they will commute. But I'm pretty sure you're still home.

Comment: It is not true that every element of order $2$ together with every element of order $3$ generates a subgroup of order $6$, so you may or may not be home, depending on your choice.

Comment: Good point. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: So I can see these elements will generate subgroups of order 2 and of order 3 respectively. And I can see that if they were disjoint then they would commute so we would have our subgroup. However I can't see, as they can't be disjoint in A5, how to get home. I can imagine that they commute in certain cases despite not being disjoint, but can't see how to find these elements other than raw computation. Is there some key information I'm missing?

Comment: You should just try and find the elements - it's not so hard!

Comment: Z6 has an element of order 6 so it can't be either of this? I'm going to try D3 though. Is playing around and using previous intuition the only way to an answer then?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to show that it can't be $\mathbb Z_6$. I think trial and error is the best way. I can't see a more enlightened approach, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist.